# Fourier transform of a two variables function with respect to one variable.

Tags: fourier-analysis

Suppose I have function  $f $ on $\mathbb R^2$ and I want to compute the fourier transform of  $f $ relative to first variable,

Is it true that for every $ t\in\mathbb R $

$\hat f ( \xi,t)=\int f (x,t)e^{-2\pi i x\xi} dx $

?

Is my definition correct?

Comment: Btw, in that other problem I was _not_ calculating an FT with respect to one variable, as you claimed - I was calculating $\hat f(0,t)$.

Comment: As a definition, of course. For a fixed $t$, define $g_t(x) := f(x,t)$. Whether or not the integral is defined for every fixed $t$ is a separate concern...